Approximation of a variant of facility location problem
I'm thinking about a variant of the facility location problem. Given a set of cities $C$ and facilities $F$, we want to open a subset $S \subseteq F$ of facilities such that the following is minimized:
$$
\max_{i \in C} d(i, S) + \sum_{j \in S} f_j,
$$
where $f_1, \dotsc, f_m$ are the opening costs of facilities and $d(\cdot, \cdot)$ is a metric.
The difference is that the first term is replaced by the objective function similar to that in the $k$-center problem. Is there a known constant approximation to this problem?

Yes, there is. It follows relative easily from the standard k-center algorithm. First guess the optimal radius $\max_i d(i, S^*)$ and then use the $k$-center algorithm.

Ignoring the costs of opening, by guessing and running $k$-center on the facilities we can get a 3-approximation. But how can we take the costs into consideration? I'm thinking about always selecting the min-cost facility but the algo could have deleted low cost facilities during the process.

See Knapsack Center which is a cost-version of k-center.

Oh thanks! I've figured it out now. Need to select the facilities and throw away the clients more carefully.

Btw, it is not natural to combine constraints such as radius and facility costs. They are two different aspects of the problem are not on the same scale. This is just a comment from the modeling aspect. It is more natural to model one as a constraint and the other as an objective like what k-center does.

Yes I agree. Turns out the algorithms can be the same though

Let me post a solution (hopefully it's correct) based on the hint given by Chandra Chekuri (comment above).
A 3-approximation
Let the optimal solution be $S^*$ then we can guess $\max_{i \in C} d(i, S^*)$ because there are at most $|F||C|$ possible numbers. Let's first assume that we know the correct guess, which is $R$. We do the following:

 Pick a $c \in C$ and select the facility in $B(c, R)$ with the lowest opening cost. Call such a client "considered."
 Remove every client within $B(c, 2R)$.
 Repeat until there are no clients left.

Analysis

 Let $S$ be the constructed facility set. We observe that by the triangle inequality, every client is at most $R+2R$ distance from $S$. So our solution's radius satisfies $\max_{i \in C}d(i, S) \leq 3R=3 \max_{i \in C}d(i, S^*)$.
 Next we show that $\sum_{j \in S}f_j \leq \sum_{j \in S^*}f_j$. Consider $B(c, R)$ for each $c \in C$ that is "considered" by our algorithm. Note that at least one facility in $S^*$ must be in each of these balls. By construction these balls are disjoint (since their centers are at least $2R$ away from each other but the radius is only $R$), which means that the facilities opened by the optimal solution in these balls are distinct. Finally, since we always choose the lowest cost facility to open in these balls, the opening cost of our algorithm is not greater than that of the optimal algorithm.

Finally, how do we do the guess? Of course in this problem the smallest $R$ possible might not be the radius of the optimal solution. But we can do the following:

 If the guessed $R$ does not allow a feasible construction (meaning some $B(c, R) \cap F = \varnothing$), then we skip it as the optimal cannot have this radius.
 For other guesses which we can make a construction on, we pick the solution with the smallest target function (not the radius). Note that least one guess is correct and for that guess the target function is a 3-approximation, then so is the construction with the smallest target function.

